# scss is not supported in express generator

Tags: express, sass, express-generator

I used the express-generator command to generate code. with CSS option as sass. It adds sassMiddleware. I changed the intendedSyntax option to false to get scss file instead of sass file. here is my code.

```
$ express --view=hbs --css=sass myapp
```

it generate

```
app.use(sassMiddleware({
  src: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
  dest: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
  indentedSyntax: true, // true = .sass and false = .scss
  sourceMap: true
}));
```

I changed indentedSyntax to false and added style.scss file. But it through 500 error on loading stylesheet.

stack trace[image]

Comment: can you please add stack trace to the post?

Comment: sure I added the stack trace

Comment: This is a compilation error. Can you verify your style.scss if it has correct scss syntax?

Comment: yes,  I missed the semicolon in scss file.

Comment: cool...I hope it worked now.

Comment: yes It works now.